# box around entries in xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

I would like to reproduce the result of the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{
&&&& \mathcal{T}\ar@{-}[dr]\ar@{-}[dl]\\
&&&\mathcal{A}^\perp\ar@{-}[dr]\ar@{-}[dl] && **[r] \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}_3\\
&&\mathcal{B}^{\perp, \mathcal{A}^\perp}\ar@{-}[dr]\ar@{-}[dl] && **[r] \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A}_2\\
& \mathcal{C}^{\perp, \mathcal{B}^\perp}\ar@{-}[dr]\ar@{-}[dl] && **[r] \mathcal{C} = \mathcal{A}_1 \\
\mathcal{D}^{\perp, \mathcal{C}^\perp} & & **[r] \mathcal{D} = \mathcal{A}_0
\ar@{.}(55,-10);(127,-10)
\ar@{.}(55,-18);(127,-18)
\ar@{.}(55,-18);(55,-10)
\ar@{.}_{=t_3}(127,-18);(127,-10) 
%
\ar@{.}(35,-23);(107,-23)
\ar@{.}(35,-32);(107,-32)
\ar@{.}(35,-23);(35,-32)
\ar@{.}^{=t_2}(107,-23);(107,-32)
%
\ar@{.}(10,-38);(82,-38)
\ar@{.}(10,-47);(82,-47)
\ar@{.}^{=t_1}(82,-38);(82,-47)
\ar@{.}(10,-38);(10,-47)
%
\ar@{.}(-7,-52);(66,-52)
\ar@{.}(-7,-61);(66,-61)
\ar@{.}^{=t_0}(66,-52);(66,-61)
\ar@{.}(-7,-52);(-7,-61)
}\]
\end{document}
```

in a more efficient and smart way (y'know, I have a life to live and stuff to do :) ). More precisely, how can I draw the boxes you see, telling xypic only a minimum informations (e.g. the nodes that the box has to cover) and more importantly in a uniform manner (same size, same length, etc.)? Here is the output I want:

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Done. Sorry!!!!

Comment: Maybe doable with Xy, but perhaps TikZ is much better at this.

Comment: I'll be glad to accept a tikz solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A starting point in `tikz`, using the `fit` library for the boxes and the `cd` library for [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) features.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, fit}
\tikzset{myboxgroup/.style={draw, densely dotted}} % style for the boxed groups

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, name=m, commutative diagrams/every cell] {
 & & \mathcal{T} & \\
 & \mathcal{A}^{\perp} & & \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}_3 \\
 \mathcal{B}^{\perp,\mathcal{A}^{\perp}} & & \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A}_2 \\
};
\node[myboxgroup, fit=(m-2-2) (m-2-4), label={right:$=t_3$}] {};
\node[myboxgroup, fit=(m-3-1) (m-3-3), label={right:$=t_2$}] {};
\path[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow/.append style={dash}]
  (m-1-3) edge (m-2-2)
  (m-1-3) edge (m-2-4)
  (m-2-2) edge (m-3-1)
  (m-2-2) edge (m-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Further information in response to a comment:**

The keys `commutative diagrams/every diagram` and `commutative diagrams/every cell` are used by the `tikz-cd` package to make a few settings at the beginning of every `tikzcd` environment. Since the `tikzcd` environment is not used here directly (I use a normal `tikzpicture` environment to allow for the fitted boxes), I set them manually. This ensures an appearance similar to that obtained using the `tikzcd` environment. The full definition of these keys is given in the [`tikz-cd` package documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-cd), section 2.1.

Comment: Wonderful! Let me doodle a bit with the library for today and if nobody else proposes something better, you are the winner

Comment: What does the "[commutative diagrams/every diagram]" part do? Also, the "commutative diagrams/every cell" part gives me a "TeX capacity exceeded" error... No clue why. If I remove it, no error, same output as you.

Comment: I added some details about these keys to the post. About the error: Is your TeX distribution up to date? I'm on an updated TeX Live 2014, with Tikz/PGF v3.0.0 and tikz-cd v0.9b.